# SQL Server return one row foreign key by use inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Table 1 - projects and the structure is

```
create table Projects 
(
    ProjectID int identity(1,1) primary key , 
    ProjectName varchar(900) not null,
    ProjectCity varchar(500) not null,
    ProjectAddress varchar(900) not null,
    ProjectStatus bit not null,
    projectCategories int not null , 

    constraint fk2 
        foreign key(projectCategories) 
            references Categories(CategoriesID )
)
```

Table 2 is

```
create table imgProject
(
    ProjectID int identity(1,1) primary key , 
    Imagecontent image  not null,
    FkProject int not null , 

    constraint fk1 
        foreign key(FkProject) 
            references Projects(ProjectID)
            on delete cascade 
)
```

How can I return project with only one row from table img project

I mean I want return all the project with only one column from table `imgProject`.

and example

After execute the query

```
id project [1] , NameProject [test] ,  Imagecontent [data]
```

not return all the row match with id foreign key on table  imgproject

Comment: Sample data and desired results might help you better explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: when i use this query it was returned all the row match from table imgproject i want only one row from table imgproject this my code <pre>select Projects.ProjectID,Projects.ProjectName,imgProject.Imagecontent from Projects  inner join  imgProject  on Projects.ProjectID = imgProject.FkProject;</pre>

Comment: Your naming conventions leave a lot to be desired. Are all of your tables' primary identity key going to be called ProjectID? Also, if there are 10 images, which one do you want?

Comment: If ProjectID is an identity in both tables, then there is no relationship between them. It is strange to give them the same name.  The imgProject table could have an ImageId as an identity but to have one called PRojectID is simply wrong when it does not relate to the Project id in the other table.

Comment: IT is a good practice to name FKs the same thing as the field in the table containing the PK. OR at worst the PK would be ID and the FK would be TABLENAMEID (where the tablename is the table containing the FK). You don't want devs to make incorrect assumptions about what theFK relates to or have to look it up every time.

Comment: You mean for each and every single project in table1 you would have multiple projects in table2 isn't it?.